Power BI embed in Nuxt application not firing events
Just trying a really simple power bi embed with powerbi-client-vue-js library.
<template>
    <div class="embed-component">
        <PowerBIReportEmbed
            :embed-config="embedConfig"
            :event-handlers="eventHandlers"
            cssClassName="powerbi-component"
            :phased-embedding="true"
            @report-obj="setReportObj"
        ></PowerBIReportEmbed>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Embed, service } from 'powerbi-client';
    import { PowerBIReportEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-vue-js';

    export default {
        components: {
            PowerBIReportEmbed,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                embedConfig: {
                    type: 'report',
                    embedUrl: '<my-embed-url>',
                    tokenType: 1,
                },
                eventHandlers: new Map([
                    ["loaded", this.loaded],
                    ["rendered", this.rendered],
                    ["error", this.error],
                ]) as Map<string, (event?: service.ICustomEvent<any>, embeddedEntity?: Embed) => void | null>,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            loaded() {
                console.log('Report Loaded');
            },
            rendered() {
                console.log('Report Rendered');
            },
            error(event?: service.ICustomEvent<any>) {
                console.log(event?.detail);
            },
            setReportObj(reportObj: Report) {
                console.log(reportObj);
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log()
        }
    }
</script>

This works fine and shows my report. Great. But it WILL NOT fire any of the event handlers I have set up. It won't even fire the report-obj one. I get no console logs from any of them. I cannot find much outside of the github repo for this library on how to do it and this looks like this should be the right set up.
The only thing really is this is in my EmbedComponent.client.vue. If I run it as an SSR component, I get a "self is not defined" error from powerbi-client library. The only way I got it to at least partly work is by making it a client facing component.
I am wondering if anyone has used this library and successfully got the event handlers to fire and function correctly.
